# Move VHD to Hyper-V

Tags: boot, windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I have a Windows 7 machine that can dual boot into Windows 2008 on a VHD file. I am now trying to move this VHD file to run as a Hyper-V image on Windows 2008.

I copied the VHD file to the Windows 2008 machine, and created a new Hyper-V machine using this disk as a hard disk. When I try to start this machine, I get the following message:

> Boot failure. Reboot and select proper boot device

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Comment: Did you set it up on a SCSI or IDE controller?  I have my boot VHDs setup on IDE and haven't had any problems.

Comment: It is set to IDE, I have tried changing it to SCSI and using different IDE controllers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this TechNet 'how to'

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/how-to-convert-a-vhd-bootable-image-into-hyper-v-vm.aspx

Apparently all you have to do is open your "System" registry hive and change the startup mode for “IntelIDE” driver from "3" to "0".

The link has all the steps required.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you also need to add two other registry entries:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ControlSet001\Control\CriticalDeviceDatabase\pci#ven_8086&dev_7111]
"ClassGUID"="{4D36E96A-E325-11CE-BFC108002BE10318}"
"Service"="intelide"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ControlSet001\Control\CriticalDeviceDatabase\pci#ven_8086&dev_7110&cc_0601]
"ClassGUID"="{4D36E97D-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}"
"Service"="isapnp"